# Wildcard with WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX doesn't filter out tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables with similar names and different schemas, say

```
project.dataset.orders_XXXXX_YYYYMMDD
```

and

```
project.dataset.orders_static_XXXXX_YYYYMMDD
```

WHERE XXXXX is a mix of numbers and letters, YYYYMMDD are dates.
Wildcard tables can be used only for tables with similar schemas, so

```
SELECT * FROM
`project.dataset.orders_*`
WHERE NOT _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'static.*'
```

WHERE clause won't limit the tables scanned. 
How can I deal with filtering out **static** tables with wildcard?

UPD: as kindly suggested in the answers, I'm refining the problem description

> the schema of the wildcard table is retrieved at query parsing...Filtering out the static tables is done at query execution.

The problem occurs at the query parsing while parsing different schemas with the following error:

```
Field name field0 does not exist in STRUCT<record1 STRUCT<field1 STRING, field2 STRING, field3 STRING, ...>, record2 STRUCT<field4 FLOAT64, field5 STRING, field6 STRING>, field7 STRING, ...>
```

The problem can be resolved with REGEXP_MATCH in legacy SQL. It's only strange not being able to solve it in standard SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The wildcard in the [FROM clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#wildcard_table_syntax) is: *
- The wildcard in the [WHERE x LIKE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#comparison_operators) clause is: %

As the _TABLE_SUFFIX is a string containing the value that matched the prefix, another option would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `project.dataset.orders*`
WHERE NOT _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE '_static%'
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix)  more examples to filter using _TABLE_SUFFIX

**UPDATE:**

In LegacySQL the function [REGEXP_MATCH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference#differences_between_table_id_and_table_suffix) can be used to retrieve the tables with a [regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax). I have tested and it seems that can work for your use case since the schemas were not evaluated in my testings:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset],'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"orders_\d{5}_*")')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This won't work however. 
Looks like the wildcard sees the static table with a different schema and throws out an error before even processing WHERE NOT condition.

Comment: That is correct. The schema of the wildcard table is retrieved at query parsing, where it uses the lastly created table that matches the prefix. Filtering out the static tables is done at query execution. You might want to add this schema error to your question to be clear. Both of the answers assume your question is about filtering at query execution time.

Comment: I replicated, the schema is retrieved at query execution. In my case when a view matched the regex it fails. I'm updating my answer, it seems that using REGEXP_MATCH can help you, but if not, please feel free to add the error to your questions as suggested by Hua Zhang.

Comment: Thank you both! I updated the question with some clarifications. It's indeed can be solved with legacy, which frankly seems more flexible for now. As far as I understand it can't be solved with standard.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I deal with filtering out static tables with wildcard?

```
SELECT * FROM
`project.dataset.orders_*`
WHERE NOT _TABLE_SUFFIX LIKE 'static%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't address the issue! The problem is not in the regexp.